# Pass respective class to typeof(__) from the value stored in variable in C#

Tags: c#, properties

I am trying to read Excel data and bulk upload the same into the respective tables in SQL database. In my Excel Worksheet, the name of worksheet represents the database table name in which the data needs to be inserted.

So in the below code in `var "tablename"` consists the worksheet name, and I need to pass the respective table model class in `typeof(____)`, inorder to get the table column names, after which the table column name from the model will be compared with database table column names and the bulk upload operation will be performed.

So can anyone please help me to pass the value stored in tableName as a class in:

```
typeof(_______).GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name);
```

**Code:**

```
var tableName = employeeData.TableName;

var sourceColumnList = typeof(ConsentReportSheetTableInfo).GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name);
```

Answer (score 2):

You might try

```
var sourceColumnList = Type.GetType(employeeData.TableName).GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name);
```

Comment: Provided the type is in the currently executing assembly or in Mscorlib otherwise you'll need a fully qualified name

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use `Assembly.GetType(name)`.

So, you could use something like:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var type = assembly.GetType(tableName);
var properties = type.GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name);
```

(This assumes that the type is in the executing assembly, of course.)

You can find the official documentation with examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.gettype?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Reflection_Assembly_GetType_System_String_).